# Symfony 3 LDAP authentication and login form error : could not complete search

Tags: ldap, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony 3.2 project, and am trying to implement an authentication process on the company's AD, via LDAP.
I don't understand everything about AD and LDAP, I'm usually more on a Linux prod environmment, but I know enough for this project, and Symfony has theorically everything I need.

I encounter a different problem depending on the service definition.

## First, the common code

**security.yml**

```
provider_company_ldap:
            ldap:
                base_dn: dc=domaine,dc=local
                search_dn: ~
                search_password: ~
                service: company.ldap
                default_roles: ROLE_USER

company_ldap_firewall:
        anonymous: true
        provider:  provider_company_ldap
        form_login_ldap:
            service: company.ldap
            login_path: company_rhag_user_login
            check_path: company_rhag_user_check
            dn_string: 'sAMAccountName={username},ou=Utilisateurs,dc=domaine,dc=local'
        pattern: ^/

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**CompanyBundle:User:login.html.twig**

```
<form action="{{ path('company_rhag_user_check') }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Login :
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ last_username }}"
                    id="username" name="_username" required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Password :
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" value=""
                    id="password"  name="_password" required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn" id="_submit" name="_submit">
                Connexion
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

---

## 1st case: service with Ldap class

Using the Ldap class, as LdapClient is marked deprecated and will be removed in 4.0:

```
services:
    company.ldap:
        class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
        arguments:
            - '%dbldap_host%'     # local ip for AD server
```

With this service, no page can display, and the error message is :

`FatalThrowableError in Ldap.php line 28: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\AdapterInterface, string given, called in C:\blahblahblah\var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 446`

## 2nd case: deprecated LdapClient class

So, I tried with the deprecated class LdapClient class :

```
services:
    company.ldap:
        class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient
        arguments:
            - '%dbldap_host%'     # local ip for AD server
```

With this, the login form displays correctly, the Symfony's toolbar displays authentication as anon., with the right `company_ldap_firewall` mentionned. Until there everything's fine if I ignore the deprecated warning.
When submitting, whatever are the credentials, I got this message :

`Could not complete search with dn "dc=domaine,dc=local", query "(sAMAccountName=loginvalue)" and filters "*"`

Of course, the best solution would be to use the non-deprecated service class, but at this point, any working solution will do.

thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: +1 I have same question. Could not complete search with dn "dc=domaine,dc=local", query "(sAMAccountName=loginvalue)" and filters "*"

Answer (score 0):

Using the ldap class you should be passing in an argument of type AdapterInterface rather than a string (this is shown in the error message you get). There is a good example of this in the docs:

[Symfony 3.2 - Authenticating against an LDAP server](https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/security/ldap.html):

```
services:
    ldap:
        class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
        arguments: ['@ext_ldap_adapter']
    ext_ldap_adapter:
        class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter
        arguments:
            -   host: my-server
                port: 389
                encryption: tls
                options:
                    protocol_version: 3
                    referrals: false
```

Where the arguments for the ext_ldap_adapter service will be your ldap config.